# if get 0 then Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated if higher then 0 is work

Tags: javascript, ajax, multithreading

I using ajax code for append result from database, the case is if i use GET with idc = 0 in URL then the code give error in console:

This the url

product?idc=0&_=1453888198332

```
Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience.
```

but if the GET is higer from zero like 1,2,3,4,...etc then the code work with data or no data.

this my ajax, this code working because i use in other project. but in this test is not.

```
var data={idc:idc};
            $.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                datatype:"html",
                url:"",
                data:data,
                cache:false,
                success: function(data) { 
                              $('#subcategory').append(data);
                }
```

how to fix this?

Thank you

Comment: The warning you see is a result of [an effort to deprecate synchronous XMLHttpRequests](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#sync-warning).  It _should_ just be a warning at the moment and not be causing any actual problems, but it's something best avoided.  If your code isn't working, it must be something else.  Unless of course your browser is implementing the _"may experiment with throwing"_ part of that note...

Comment: This is a warning not error! Not sure why it works with non-zero values..

Comment: I do not seen async:false i your ajax call..besides empty url... are you sure, that is the code actually running?

Comment: but this generates NOT a Synchronous XMLHttpRequest ...

Comment: if the product?idc=1&_=1453888198332 the network stop, if ?idc=0 the network lost like reload but not reload just give html template